# How to install Android SDK for unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk

How to install Android SDK for building an app in Unity?

I used the guide and followed the steps.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/building-your-unity-game-android-device-testing

After implementing the steps I still can not find the sdk.exe which is needed for the build proces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such file as sdk.exe

Default path of SDK folder is: `C:\Users\[yourName]\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk`

There is a file named `SDK Manager.exe` in that address where you can install or update SDK modules.

After installing SDK and JDK you need to set their paths in `Unity -> Edit -> Preferences...`:

[image]

In `Unity -> File -> Build Settings` select `Android` from platforms list and click `Build`:

[image]

Or you can click on `Build and Run` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) if `Device` is already set in `Edit -> Project Settings -> Editor` to `Any Android Device`

That's all you need to do for building your game for android.

*you may also need to move Java Path to the first position in the PATH variable in environment variables.*

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to look for "exe",

On unity -> edit -> external tools in the sdk "SDK" part you need to fill the path to the android sdk folder (not file) something like:

> C:/AndroidDevelopment/android-sdk

for the "JDK" part you need to fill your java path something like:

> C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_50